# Web page is showing weird unicode(?) letters: \u200e

Tags: django-errors

How can I remove that? I Tried so many things and I am exhausted of trying to defeat this error by myself. I spent the last 3 hours looking at this and trying to get through it and I surrender to this code. Please help.

The first "for" statement grabs article titles from news.google.com
The second "for" statement grabs the time of submisssion from that article on news.google.com.

This is on django btw and this page shows the list of article titles and their time of submission in a list, going down. The weird unicode letters are popping up from the second "for" statement which is the time submissions. Here  is my views.py:

```
def articles(request):
""" Grabs the most recent articles from the main news page """
import bs4, requests

list = []
list2 = []
url = 'https://news.google.com/'
r = requests.get(url)
try:
    r.raise_for_status() == True
except ValueError:
    print('Something went wrong.')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

for (listarticles) in soup.find_all('h2', 'esc-lead-article-title'):
    if listarticles is not None:
        a = listarticles.text
        list.append(a)

for articles_times in soup.find_all('span','al-attribution-timestamp'):
    if articles_times is not None:
        b = articles_times.text
        list2.append(b)

list = zip(list,list2)
context = {'list':list}

return render(request, 'newz/articles.html', context)
```